# Linux and Azure AD sync possible?

Tags: ldap, active-directory, openldap

I am currently considering to shuffle some infrastructure around, but my question boils down to:

> Can I sync a list of users and passwords to Azure AD (only for Office 365) from a linux samba server?

Currently there's an on premise Windows Server that doesn't do much apart from DNS and user management for different services through the Active Directory. My thought was: why not ditch that for a Linux Server with one of the open source replacements.

Currently I'm stuck on the office 365 user sync and posts that state that Open LDAP and other possibilities will be available in the *near future*. Last update: 2014.

Comment: Did you found a solution?
I'm looking for a way to set the password of an AAD user by the hash-value only, as the AD Connect tool do.
My own question: [My own Azure AD password synchronization tool](https://serverfault.com/questions/996771/my-own-azure-ad-password-synchronization-tool?noredirect=1#comment1296494_996771)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a tool "right now" that will allow you to synchronise accounts from a Samba DC to Azure Active Directory. You should be able to set up your spare Windows Server as a secondary Domain Controller and then synchronise from that using [Azure AD Connect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect), though.

Another option - albeit a heavyweight one - might be to go the Federation route and use your own SAML authentication server(s) to authenticate access to Office 365. This is not for the faint-hearted; I've not yet managed to get Microsoft's Federation-based authentication to work with exclusively Microsoft software in the loop, so I suspect you would be embarking on a voyage of discovery without any knowledge that the edge of the world really wasn't a gigantic waterfall...

In practical terms you might get a more hands-on answer over on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thank you! Secondary DC would be a possibility, but that's still another server to maintain, (which I really just want to bury). I'll try Server Fault too and try to provide more detail, thank you!